# The -p option in the bash history command?

Tags: bash, history-expansion

From `man bash`,

> history **-p** arg [arg ...]
>
> ...
>
> -p
>
> Perform **history substitution** on the following args and display the
>   result on the standard output.

What does '**history substitution**' mean here?  Can you provide an example of its use?

Thanks.

---

I understand command line history substitution, and already tried things like this:

```
history -p "!23:1"
```

But this is not dependent on -p, as `xx "!23:1"` does the same thing.

Comment: I suspect this is if you turn off history expansion, you still have a way to recall history: try `set +H; echo !23; history -p !23` -- re-enable history expansion with `set -H`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have history expansion enabled, and run `history -p "!23:1"`, the expansion happens *before* the `history` builtin sees the designator `!23:1`, since history expansion takes place even within double-quotes.

However, if you either disable history expansion, or protect the exclamation mark with single quotes or a backslash, so that the builtin gets to handle it, you'll see that `history -p` *outputs* the result of that history expansion:

```
$ true
$ history -p '!!'
true
```

I assume the purpose of it is to be able to script history expansions.